# Replace spaces in all files in a directory with underscores

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have found some similar questions here but not this specific one and I do not want to break all my files. I have a list of files and I simply need to replace all spaces with underscores. I know this is a `sed` command but I am not sure how to generically apply this to every file.

I do not want to rename the files, just modify them in place.

Edit: To clarify, just in case it's not clear, I only want to replace whitespace within the files, file names should not be changed.

Comment: are you replacing whitespaces within the file, or are you replacing the file names whitespaces?

Comment: @Jouster500 white space within the files

Comment: `sed 's/ /_/g' infile > outfile`

Comment: @SteveSummit That's only a single file. I want a method to apply this to all files in a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/ /_/g' {} \;
```

`find` grabs all items in the directory (and subdirectories) that are files, and passes those filenames as arguments to the `sed` command using the `{} \;` notation. The `sed` command it appears you already understand.

if you only want to search the current directory, and ignore subdirectories, you can use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/ /_/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2 part problem. Step 1 is providing the proper sed command, 2 is providing the proper command to replace all files in a given directory.

Substitution in sed commands follows the form `s/ItemToReplace/ItemToReplaceWith/pattern`, where `s` stands for the substitution and `pattern` stands for how the operation should take place. [According to this super user post](https://superuser.com/questions/112834/how-to-match-whitespace-in-sed), in order to match whitespace characters you must use either `\s` or `[[:space:]]` in your sed command. The difference being the later is for POSIX compliance. Lastly you need to specify a global operation which is simply /g at the end. This simply replaces all spaces in a file with underscores. 
Substitution in sed commands follows the form `s/ItemToReplace/ItemToReplaceWith/pattern`, where `s` stands for the substitution and `pattern` stands for how the operation should take place. [According to this super user post](https://superuser.com/questions/112834/how-to-match-whitespace-in-sed), in order to match whitespace characters you must use either just a space in your sed command, `\s`, or `[[:space:]]`. The difference being the last 2 are for whitespace catching (tabs and spaces), with the last needed for POSIX compliance. Lastly you need to specify a global operation which is simply /g at the end.

Therefore, your sed command is

> `sed s/ /_/g FileNameHere`

However this only accomplishes half of your task. You also need to be able to do this for every file within a directory. Unfortunately, wildcards won't save us in the sed command, as `* > *` would be ambiguous. Your only solution is to iterate through each file and overwrite them individually. [For loops by default should come equipped with file iteration syntax](https://ss64.com/bash/for.html), and when used with wildcards expands out to all files in a directory. However sed's used in this manner appear to completely lose output when redirecting to a file. To correct this, you must specify sed with the `-i` flag so it will edit its files. Whatever item you pass after the `-i` flag will be used to create a backup of the old files. If no extension is passed (`-i ''` for instance), no backup will be created.

Therefore the final command should simply be

> `for i in *;do sed -i '' 's/ /_/g' $i;done`

Which looks for all files in your current directory and echos the sed output to all files (Directories do get listed but no action occurs with them).

Comment: I actually tried your version (stumbled on my self) and `$i > $>i` seems to overwrite the files with blank data. I think you need to use the `-i` flag to perform in-place editing to be safe.

Comment: @DylanLawrence Yes it would seem it would accomplish this particular task, but it renames the old file with the old data. Ill retinker with the command

Answer (score 0):

Well...  since I was trying to get something running I found a method that worked for me:

```
for file in `ls`; do sed -i 's/ /_/g' $file; done
```

Comment: you could probably take that command further and have it ignore directory files as well with a flag for the `ls`

Comment: That script contains at least 3 anti-patterns. Don't parse the output of `ls` and don't write shell loops just to manipulate text, and don't leave your shell variables unquoted. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219, and just google quoting shell variables.